# VuePress Sidebar incorrectly rendering

Tags: vuepress

I was looking for a solution to automatic generation of the VuePress sidebar and found this [module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elDgH.png) which was recommended in this [tutorial - solution2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnGCS.png)

I'm trying to get it working as described however the sidebar displays the actual folder path to the html rather than just the name as can be seen below,  i've tried a different folder structure, adding and removing MD files but i cannot get the sidebar to display correctly. Would anyone know how I can fix this / what i've done wrong?

[image]

Config.js:

```
const getConfig = require("vuepress-bar"); 
module.exports = {
    title: 'Hello VuePress',
    description: 'Just playing around',
    themeConfig: {
      ...getConfig(`${__dirname}/..`)
            }
}
```

Sidebar result :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding the correct front matter to my MD files, title and permalink